# Possible to create event using Google CalendarApp and send to somebody else?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have written a script that queues reminders, and emails them a delegated user. I would like to send calendar events to the person, instead of emails.

My question is: Is it possible to create an event using the CalendarApp and send it to another gCalendar user? I see API's for querying ownership, but not for setting it. An event with anonymous ownership would also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches here.

1. You can setup your script so that it is runs as the user who will want the calendar invite. You can see this under the Publish menu option
2. OR you can add the person as a guest using the [addGuest](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_calendarevent#addGuest) API.

There are no other ways to access another person's calendar and adding an event owned by them. Sounds the given the current setup #2 would be the simplest.

Comment: Using method 2, the user running the script will also have the event added to their calendar. This is not desirable as the script is generating events to delegate to an arbitrary user. Is subscription to an event that you create necessary?

Comment: You don't need to use your own calendar, you can create a 'on purpose' one that you use therefor only.